# Left join with the Hierarchy table after pivot

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run this query. Here i am making a hierarchy with level and path of the levels and then left join to another table. But i am getting error Invalid identifier "a.level"

```
WITH HierCTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Temp_table_1 ORDER BY "ParentId", "Level")

SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT "NodeName","ParentId","Level",INDEX, MAX(VALUE) OVER 
  (PARTITION BY "Level", INDEX) CT,PATH FROM
  (SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH("Level", '\\') 
  PATH,"NodeName","ParentId","Level" FROM Temp_table_1
    start with "ParentId" is not null connect by
    prior "Level" = "ParentId"),
   TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(PATH, '\\')))

PIVOT(MAX(CT) FOR INDEX IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) AS HierTable  
("NodeName","ParentId","Level",PATH,"Level1","Level2","Level3",
 "Level4","Level5", "Level6","Level7","Level8","Level9","Level10", "Level11") as a

 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
 "Col1" AS "Level",
 TRY_CAST("vaule1" AS INT ) AS "NewValue1",
 TRY_CAST("value2" AS INT) AS "NewValue2"

FROM Temp_table_2
WHERE "class1" = 'AAAA') as b
ON b."Level" = a."Level"
```

Any idea, what is wrong in this query and how can i modified it? Thanks!

Comment: I think there may be more problems with the query than just the error you are seeing. Can you format the code properly and update your question with the formatted code please? If you format your SQL code you will probably be able to find the issue yourself.

Comment: The query works fine till the Left join, after i put Left join it is throwing error.

Comment: It is always a good idea to post the error message you are getting (and any DDL need to reproduce the error)

Comment: You need to indicate which DBMS you are using. MySQL or Snowflake. Different SQL DBMSes use different SQL "dialects".   You also need to format your code. Using an editor that will highlight any syntax errors will help you in your SQL journey

Comment: @PaulVernon Hey thanks! I am using Snowflake for this query and you ar right the editor helps with syntax error